# Is there a schema category for hyperstructures?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, model-categories, higher-algebra

I am completely fascinated by Niels Baas' notion of [**hyperstructures**](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/hyperstructure), chiefly because I can see how such gadgets could be used in modeling both biological and social systems, or other evolutionary systems (the basic intuition being that they describe complex systems obtained by "glueing" lower cells of arbitrary shapes).

Now, here is my question: there is a known  list of [**geometric shape categories**](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric+shape+for+higher+structures)

the globe category $\mathbb{G}$

the simplex category $\Delta$

the cube category $\square$

the tree category $ \Omega$

the opetopic category $\mathbb{O}$

each one modeling a particular notion of higher categorical structure.

What is then the shape category for Baas' hyperstructures?

One would think that it is a small category including all of the above, a schema to glue "stuff" along arbitrary borders. Anyone has a clue?

**ADDENDUM**

Re-reading the article in n-Lab which I have quoted above and following some basic intuition, it looks to me that such a schema category is made up of  arbitrary posets closed downward, the maps will be poset maps, and glueing correspond to having a common (up to isos) poset, or something like that. This would definitely generalize both $\Delta$ and $ \Omega$, which are small categories of posets. But I have to admit that this is still very tentative...